Каким способом парсить асемблерный код?
Есть у меня машинный код для виртуальной машины, но хочу создать для него ассемблер, так как писать все на машинном коде это ещё то удовольствие...
Но вот проблема, я не знаю каким способом мне парсить код
Что вы посоветуете? может подойдут регулярные выражения, может пойдут простые методи для работы со строками (split(), start/endsWith()..) или есть что то другое, чего я не знаю, так как в интернете не могу найти примеры трансляторов, ну и написанием трансляторов я не занимался раньше и только начинаю это
Если вам не сложно наведите пример разбора какой то инструкции
Пусть будет:
mova eax, 0xFF
inc eax
movc [eax], 0x0A

На выходе должно получится как то так:
0xAA 0x00 0xFf
0xCE 0x00 0x00
0xAC 0x00 0x0A

(0x00 или просто 0 - указатель на eax если что, но можно использовать для заполнения свободного пространства, а длина инструкций 3 байта)

Да сделайте сначала максимально просто - через регулярные выражения, например. Просто, чтобы хоть как-то работало. Или даже просто через split. У ассемблера довольно простой синтаксис (если не учитывать всякие макроинструкции), не нужно прямо что-то слишком сложное сразу придумывать. Сделайте сначала минимальный рабочий прототип, потом можно будет переделать (или не переделывать).

Не стоит плодить вопросы-дубликаты. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1585574/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0#comment2860873_1585574

@user7860670 С чего вы взяли что вопрос о создании компилятора и вопрос как нужно парсить асемблерный код является дубликатом?

Если бы вы почитали рекомендованную там книжку, то знали бы, парсинг исходного кода - первый шаг в работе компилятора.

@insolor "максимально просто" редко сочетается с "через регулярные выражения"

@user7860670 вполне сочетается. Через максимально простые регулярные выражения будет максимально просто. Но в целом - да, это отдельный навык, как не переусложнять.

@user7860670 парсинг исходного кода - первый шаг в работе компилятора сначало обратите внимание о чем я спрашивал в вопросе о компиляторе и в этом вопросе, во первых в 1 вопросе я спросил как сделать умный генератор кода а не как в общем написать компилятор, а в этом как парсить асемблер а не как компилятор создать, а во вторых парсинг асемблера и парсинг кода высокоуровневого языка это немного разные вещи, так как тут я имел ввиду разобрать код на части и их транслировать в байт код, а в случае 2 варианта как парсить код, разбить на токены, и генерировать ast

И эти 2 вопроса соответственно имеют разный смысл и не могут являться дубликатом

И как бы первый шаг компиляции это лексический анализ, а не парсинг
